# Drastically decreased performance of webview in Jelly Bean?

Tags: android, cordova, android-webview, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am developing a game in Javascript/HTML/CSS and packaging it into an Android app with Phonegap. The game includes a bunch of animations (many done with jquery) such as fadeins/fadeouts, div movements, etc. - nothing out of the ordinary but certainly heavy relative to most websites out there.

In ICS, the game runs extremely well - very high fps, no lag, etc. However, now that I upgraded my Galaxy Nexus to 4.1, Jelly Bean has resulted in the game slowing down to a crawl. Fade ins are now more akin to show, I constantly notice slow responsiveness to touch, the projectiles being shot keep occasionally freezing, etc.

I realize this is quite general, but I am just curious if anyone else is seeing / has seen something similar in their applications and if you have suggestions for how to fix this mess. Any tips are much appreciated.

UPDATE: after enabling 3D transforms and rewriting part of the code to include everything in Animation Frame the issue seems to be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after enabling 3D transforms and rewriting part of the code to include everything in Animation Frame the issue seems to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

More a generic statement then answering your question

Have you tried using webkit animations rather then Jquery ones ? These are more likely to be processed by the GPU.

Comment: Yep, tried both webkit animations and Jquery ones and did not see a difference - just as bad.. :(

I will also try the newly released Phonegap and see if it helps. I will keep this thread updated.